# View Pager with tab layout in bottom wont work?

Tags: android

I want to use tab bar at bottom ...
this is my Xml file ...
Its shown in bottom but its overlapping on viewpager's fragment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<include layout="@layout/app_bar" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/colorMiddarkGray"
        app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_color_selector" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_above="@id/sliding_tabs"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

</RelativeLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:itemBackground="@color/colorMiddarkGray">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/nav_view_header"
            layout="@layout/nav_header_main" />

        <include layout="@layout/nav_menu" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

But output dont show in full..
my viewpager not getting bottom padding or margin ...
I want to show bottom tab layout with view pager

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I changed `RelativeLayout` to `LinearLayout` because `layout_weight` only works with `LinearLayout` children and then changed the order to display `ViewPager` followed by `TabLayout`. Try this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_above="@id/sliding_tabs"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/colorMiddarkGray"
        app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_color_selector" />



</LinearLayout>
```